# How to log install4j installation process in windows?

Tags: install4j

I have already tried /create-i4j-log argument as given in install4j docs but that's not giving all logs

Answer (score 0):

A few notes on logging in the context of install4j:

- The `/create-i4j-log` argument is for getting debug output from the native part of the installer.
- stdout is not logged
- stderr is printed to a file "error.log" next to the installer.
- Logging output for the `.install4j/installation.log` file is produced with calls to `com.install4j.api.Util.logInfo/logError`

Comment: How to log stdout then? I can see error.log file and installation.log, but cannot find the output in windows what I get on console when installer is run in linux

Comment: For testing purposes you can select the "Windows console executable" property of the installer, then you will see stdout output